# Two colors background Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, background, background-color

I am programming an Android activity and it should have a background of a color in its upper side and another color in its bottom side.

The relative layout used is padded.

What I usually do is using non padded relative layout and dividing it in in upper and bottom relative layout, these u/l are divided in other padded relative layout.

This assure me that all the activity area has the background color that it should have. 
The padded area assures that the widgets are around the centre of the activity.

But now I have an already programmed activity and the upper side widgets and the bottom side ones are related each other so I can't divide the relative layout easily.

Any advice?

Comment: the upper color takes 50% of screen and the bottom 50%?

Comment: I think it's about 40/60

Comment: Ok, give mi a minute :)

Comment: Sure. Take all The time you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on this layout for your activity. There is only one `RelativeLayout` with two backgrounds. One is set to the layout itself, the other is set to an empty `View` that is positioned under the views on the top. The only disadvantage is you have to remove `padding` from the `RelativeLayout` and replace it with `margin` set to your views. I guess it's not a big deal.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#59C2F2">

    <!-- This is the last TextView of top part, below it the bg will be different -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="This represents top elements"/>

    <!-- This View must be placed before any elements from the bottom part -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#004892" />

    <!-- Now you can place your bottom elements and align them with the to ones -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/bottom_background"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="This is the bottom part"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Only one last question: how should I implement the margins? In the first relative layout?

Comment: Intead of `RelativeLayout` setting the padding that would for instance put the `TextView` 16dp from the screen egde you set margin to the `TextView` itself. If you want several element aligned to the same line you set the margin to the first one and align the rest to this one. It is in the provided example

Comment: Plus 1 for the intuitive solution

Answer (score 2):

First add this to your `/values/attrs.xml`. If the file doesn't exists, create it as a resource type.

```
<declare-styleable name="TwoColoredView">
    <attr name="topColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="bottomColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="topColorHeightPercent" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Next create a `TwoColoredView` class and put it somewhere where you keep your custom views

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import your.package.R;

/**
 * Created by Bojan on 27.4.2015.
 */

public class TwoColoredView extends View {

    private int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;
    private Paint topPaint, bottomPaint;
    final int defaultTopColor = 0xFFFF0000;
    final int defaultBottomColor = 0xFF0000FF;
    private int topHeight = 40;

    public TwoColoredView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public TwoColoredView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TwoColoredView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int style) {

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.TwoColoredView, style, style);

        int topColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.TwoColoredView_topColor, defaultTopColor);
        int bottomColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.TwoColoredView_bottomColor, defaultBottomColor);
        topHeight = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.TwoColoredView_topColorHeightPercent, 40);

        typedArray.recycle();

        topPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        topPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        topPaint.setColor(topColor);

        bottomPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        bottomPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        bottomPaint.setColor(bottomColor);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight * 0.01f * topHeight, topPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, measuredHeight * 0.01f * topHeight, measuredWidth, measuredHeight, bottomPaint);
    }
}
```

Now create a layout for your fragment/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <your.package.TwoColoredView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:topColorHeightPercent="40"
        app:topColor="#FFFF0000"
        app:bottomColor="#FF0000FF"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Other stuff goes here -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Hehe.. I'm the middle bro!"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the final result

[image: preview]

Comment: You need to add styleable to your attrs. Check step one.

Comment: Done , but   (error: Invalid start tag declare-styleable attrs.xml)

Comment: Start and ens tag should be <resources>. I can make a simple project and zip it, if you have trouble?

Comment: This still just sets the backgrounds edge on fixed position, it does not get it from the elements position within the `RelativeLayout`. This won't work on different screens/screen orientations.

Comment: Now Compiling. By default, i haven't a fragment/layout folder. Should i create it manually? And move the existing activity there?

Comment: No no.. fragment and activity layout is the same. You should already have a layout folder where you have your current activity.

Comment: @Lamorak this works on all different screen sizes, this even works if the view if not taking up the whole screen! It is based on it's measured width and height, but since I have set it's height to be equal to the parent, this is ok.

Comment: Well the thing is you have several elements in a `RelativeLayout` and you want them have different background than other group of elements. These groups won't always split the screen 40/60 so you want the background to be split according to the views not to the fixed value. That is how I understand the question.